# Find the Diameter of data in a text file using R

Tags: r, igraph, graph-theory

I have a file consist of 20000 lines and 3 columns [Here you can find a sample from the out1.txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7X9f.png). I am trying to import the lines to R then find the Diameter for each 20 lines (I mean to divide the 20000 lines into 1000 parts each  part consist of 20 lines) so first I need to read each 20 lines separately then apply the diameter function in R.

After that I need to read each part as a graph then to find the diameter.

The name of the file which contain the 20000 lines is (out1.txt) and the name of the file I will use to write on it the diameter for the 100 parts is outfile (so outfile will consist of 100 lines each line represent the diameter of the 20 lines in out1.txt)

The code is:

```
setwd("Desktop")
outfile<- file('outfile', 'w')
library("igraph")
X<-read.table("out1.txt")
l=1;
t=1;
while (t<=20000){
for (i in t:t+19){
for (k in 1:3) {
T<- matrix(nrow=20, ncol=3);
T[l,k]<-X[i,k];
}
l=l+1;
}
t=t+20;
l=1;
gg<-graph.data.frame(T,directed=FALSE)
C<-diameter(gg,directed=FALSE,weights=NULL)
writeLines(C,con=outfile)
}
```

I trouble an error but I can't understand what is the meaning of it exactly, the error:

```
Error in writeLines(C, con = outfile) : invalid 'text' argument
```

Thanks a lot for any advice or help

Comment: Please put samples of data as copy-pastable text, rather than images

Comment: As a quick fix, `writeLines(as.character(C), con=outfile)` should do it

Comment: Yes, also, there is `get.data.frame` function, in the `igraph` package, wrap `diameter` around it.

Comment: @apom  a p o m    I tried the addition (as.character(C)) but it didn't work and it gave me this error => (There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50))

Comment: @MarioGS GS   I didn't understand why should I use the get.data.frame function ?

Comment: Sorry, `get.data.frame` is useful when you want to export the edge list or adj. matrix. Please refer to my solution.

Comment: @MarioGS GS are you sure that there is no problem in the while & for loops ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can simplify a bit your code since you want blocks of 20. Also, I think you need to append the outcomes because otherwise, you will overwrite yours in each loop. Try this:

```
 DF <- data.frame(C1=sample(1:1000,200), C2=sample(1:1000,200))
outfile<- file('outfile.txt')
for(i in seq(1,200, 20)){
  for(j in seq(20,200, 20)){
    g <- as.character(diameter(graph.data.frame(DF[i:j, ], directed = F),directed=FALSE,weights=NULL))
    write.table(g,"outfile.txt", append = T, col.names = F, row.names = F)
  }
}
close(outfile)
```

Comment: Yes it is working but giving wrong answers!! I took the first 20 lines and I found the diameter for them alone, it was 5 but using this code it is 1 !!

Comment: I see, I believe that there is an issue with the conversion between `igraph` an `as.character`, not related to the logic in the code. Please, try with `as.integer`.

Comment: I double checked myself, there is no mistake or error in the conversion. I suspect that the issue is that since we are using append, we have to start with a clean file everytime you run the loop.

Comment: Thanks but in your code you find the diameter for any 20 randomly lines and I want to find it for each 20 in order ==> the diameter for the first 20 then the diameter for the lines from 21 to 40 and then from 41 to 60 and so on...

Comment: Because of that I used in my code the matrix of 20 lines and 3 columns to sort each 20 consecutive lines in a matrix then to find the diameter for this matrix but unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: That's not true, there is no randomization in `seq`, run the separately and see for yourself ` seq(1,200, 20)`, `seq(20,200, 20)`, this is in that order.

Comment: I bet it is, delete the file before each run of the loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help but if it is possible why you used in your code this function and what does it mean:                                                                  (DF <- data.frame(C1=sample(1:1000,200), C2=sample(1:1000,200)))

Comment: I used that just to generate data, you didn't provide a complete reproducible example, you could have use `dput`, to paste a subset of your data.